# What is cup product all about?

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Question is as stated in the title.

What is cup product in group cohomology is all about?

I am looking at the following books

- Class field theory - Bonn lectures Neukirch
- Cohomology of Number fields - Neukirch
- Cohomological methods in Group theory  - Ararat Babakhanian

Let $G$ be a finite group and $A$ be a $G$ module.

I was told by some one that cup products gives a graded ring structure on Homology groups $$\{H^q(G,A)\}_{q\geq 0}$$

As we have more structre, we can understand the group $G$ and module $A$ better.

Given $G$ modules $A$ and $B$ we have $G$ module $A\otimes B$ and for each $p,q\geq 0$ we have a bilinear map (a cup product) as follows

$$H^p(G,A)\times H^q(G,B)\xrightarrow{\cup} H^{p+q}(G,A\otimes B)$$

Though the definitions are not same in these three books, let us assume we do have a product with some properties.

So, how does this give a graded ring structure on cohomology groups?

As $p^{\rm{th}}$ cohomology (of some module) and $q^{\rm{th}}$ cohomology (of another module) is mapping to $(p+q)^{\rm{th}}$ cohomology (of some another module) there is some hope to get some graded structure.

As we are looking for ring structure on $\{H^q(G,A)\} $ we expect to consider special case when $A=B$. So, we have

$$H^p(G,A)\times H^q(G,A)\xrightarrow{\cup} H^{p+q}(G,A\otimes A)$$

So, we have a product into module $A\otimes A$ but we want a map into module $A$.

I do not see any obvious map from $H^{p+q}(G,A\otimes A)$ to $H^{p+q}(G,A)$

We do have some obvious map $A\rightarrow A\otimes A$ but this gives a map from $H^{p+q}(G,A)$ to $H^{p+q}(G,A\otimes A)$ but not the other way.

So, how do we make this into a ring? And, What is this cup product in group cohomology all about?

I have seen some questions related to cup products in stack exchange but could not understand it better.

Comment: Have you seen the cup/cap products in algebraic topology? It has a geometric origin (but it is best that somebody other than me explain that :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Sir,  I have not seen cup/cap products in algebraic topology..

Comment: I don't think that any $A$ will be sufficient to give a ring structure. Usually we require $A$ to be a ring and $A \otimes A \to A$ is induced by the multiplication map.

Comment: Ok. Can you be a bit more specific? Can you give some reference? @Improve

Comment: You said you needed a map $A \otimes A \to A$. By definition of tensor product, the multiplication map (which is a bilinear map coming from the fact that A is a ring) $A \times A \to A$ induces a map $A \otimes A \to A$. Look up the definition of the tensor product if you are unsure about this.  Brown Cohomology of Groups treats the subject.

Comment: @Improve : in case when A is a ring I understand that there is a map from tensor product... My question was to look for a ring structure in case of general $G$ module.. You are saying for arbitrary modules it is not necessary true..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: $H^q(G;A)$ will not be a ring in general. You would need a $G$-module map $A\otimes A\to A$ to get an internal cup product. This rarely happens (but one case when it does is when $A$ is a ring viewed as a trivial $G$-module).

Comment: @MarkGrant : Ok.. thanks.. Can you give some reference that says more about this...

Comment: Chapter V of Brown, in particular Section 3.